# How link to any local file with markdown syntax?

Tags: file, hyperlink, markdown

I have a local markdown file containing several links and I want that links head to local file like pdf.

I use the following syntax:

```
[my link](file:///C:/my_file.pdf)
```

But when I open my markdown file into a Firefox page and click on the link, nothing happens.

What exactly have I missed? Is it possible to open local file?

Comment: Also answered here, seems to be a duplicate question?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58317580/5890679

Comment: Vim highlights markdown nicely, including clickable web links. Alas *local* links, though highlighted, will not open.

Comment: You can use https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/ as well. It works great.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

How are you opening the rendered Markdown?

If you host it over HTTP, i.e. you access it via `http://` or `https://`, most modern browsers will refuse to open local links, e.g. with `file://`. This is a [security feature](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work):

> For security purposes, Mozilla applications block links to local files (and directories) from remote files. This includes linking to files on your hard drive, on mapped network drives, and accessible via [Uniform Naming Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) (UNC) paths. This *prevents* a number of unpleasant possibilities, including:
>
> - Allowing sites to detect your operating system by checking default installation paths
> - Allowing sites to exploit system vulnerabilities (e.g., `C:\con\con` in Windows 95/98)
> - Allowing sites to detect browser preferences or read sensitive data

There are some workarounds listed on that page, but my recommendation is to avoid doing this if you can.

Comment: As I said, I open my markdown file with Mozilla Firefox 40.0.3 with the plug-in 'Markdown Viewer'.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that plug-in before ;-) I tried it with the HTML export (what I assumed "Firefox page" meant) of MarkdownPad. Please check the plug-in's help/support channels.

Answer (score 195):

None of the answers worked for me. But inspired in BarryPye's answer I found out it works when using relative paths!

```
# Contents from the '/media/user/README_1.md' markdown file:

Read more [here](./README_2.md) # It works!
Read more [here](file:///media/user/README_2.md) # Doesn't work
Read more [here](/media/user/README_2.md) # Doesn't work
```

Comment: Starting off a url path with "./" implies look in local dir, while starting with "/" implies "look in base dir."  This is a widespread Linux convention.  I suspect maybe you didn't have the full base dir down?

Comment: How is this different from @BarryPye's answer?

Comment: @javadba The exclamation point (!) in BarryPye's answer renders the file as an image. The question refers to a link to another file. (I know, slow, slow, response to your question but I thought others might want to know the answer.)

Comment: It's important not to have a space between the ] and ( characters.

Comment: @jbustamovej If there are spaces in the filename, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61224440/12131087) by Zikoat

Comment: @BringBackCommodore64 how do you open a PDF file that is in another path (another local folder in your computer)?

Comment: @nekovolta Go back in the tree directory and then navigate to wherever the PDF is. Example:  `[Book](../../docs/mybook.pdf)`. So i go back with `../../` (assuming the PDF folder is two folders down from the local MD file) and then enter its folder with `/docs/`

Comment: @HoldOffHunger: the syntax `./` or `../` is not Linux specific but defined in URL parsing specification: https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#path-state

Comment: If the source and destination files are on different drives you will need to do something like (./././C:/....)

Answer (score 47):

After messing around with @BringBackCommodore64 answer I figured it out

```markdown
[link](file:///d:/absolute.md)    # absolute filesystem path
[link](./relative1.md)            # relative to opened file
[link](/relativeToProject.md)     # relative to opened project
```

All of them tested in `Visual Studio Code` and working,

**Note**: The absolute and relative to opened project path work in editor but don't work in markdown preview mode!

Comment: your Note is very important!

Comment: As of today relative link to opened project become broken in VSCode. Just now updated to 1.61.1 and it is broken.

Comment: @user1325696, yeah, it still works in editor though.

Comment: What do you mean by "opened project"? Looks like a file.

Comment: @gargoylebident the root path of the folder which `vscode` is opened in

Comment: @Ali80 so then what is the ".md" part for? And what would linking to a folder even look like? Would it open File Explorer when I click on it?

Answer (score 36):

You link to a local file the same way you link to local images.  Here is an example to link to file `start_caQtDM_7id.sh` in the same directory as the markdown source:

```
![start_caQtDM_7id.sh](./start_caQtDM_7id.sh)
```

Comment: This "!" is important! Thanks!

Comment: It's part of the Github flavored markdown syntax to render an image, see "Images" under https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

Answer (score 24):

If you have spaces in the filename, try these:

```
[file](./file%20with%20spaces.md)
[file](<./file with spaces.md>)
```

First one seems more reliable

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem and what you are asking. Is the question: which of the file name is more reliable?

Comment: Perfect! `[file](<./file with spaces.md>)` was what i was looking for

Comment: The original question referenced links to .pdf documents but all the answers reference .md documents. For anyone skimming through the answers - this answer works with .pdf documents. Your document should open in your chosen .pdf viewer if you ctrl-click the link in your .md document.

Answer (score 6):

This is a old question, but to me it still doesn't seem to have a complete answer to the OP's question. The chosen answer about security being the possible issue is actually often **not** the problem when using the Firefox 'Markdown Viewer' plug-in in my experience. Also, the OP seems to be using MS-Windows, so there is the added issue of specifying different drives.

So, here is a little more complete yet simple answer for the 'Markdown Viewer' plug-in on Windows (and other Markdown renderers I've seen): just enter the local path as you would normally, and if it is an absolute path make sure to start it with a slash. So:

```
[a relative link](../../some/dir/filename.md)
[Link to file in another dir on same drive](/another/dir/filename.md)
[Link to file in another dir on a different drive](/D:/dir/filename.md)
```

That last one was probably what the OP was looking for given their example.
Note this can also be used to display directories rather than files.

Though late, I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, for absolute path, putting a slash before the drive name works for me `[link](/J:/dir/filename.md)`

Answer (score 5):

> **Thank you drifty0pine!**

The first solution, it´s works!

```
[a relative link](../../some/dir/filename.md)
[Link to file in another dir on same drive](/another/dir/filename.md)
[Link to file in another dir on a different drive](/D:/dir/filename.md)
```

but I had need put  more `../` until the folder where was my file, like this:

```
[FileToOpen](../../../../folderW/folderX/folderY/folderZ/FileToOpen.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in the same directory as the one where the .md is, then just putting `[Click here](MY-FILE.md)` should work.

Otherwise, can create a path from the root directory of the project. So if the entire project/git-repo root directory is called 'my-app', and one wants to point to my-app/client/read-me.md, then try `[My hyperlink](/client/read-me.md)`.

At least works from Chrome.

Comment: Thanks!  No need for ! when in same directory

Answer (score 1):

It seems most Markdown viewers won't support non http(s) URLs. Since markdown does support some HTML tags, why not use that

```html
<a href="file:///path/to/local/file.pdf">link</a>
```

This redirects fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact do almost anything behind an MD hyperlink by utilising Windows shortcuts.

To test this for yourselves, create a link like *[Typora](.\Typora.exe.lnk)* and place an actual Windows shortcut into the folder alongside the markdown file (TestMe.MD) called Typora.exe.lnk.

Then open the MD file in Typora and Ctrl-Click the link, and it should execute whatever you linked in that shortcut, opened in any folder you specified in that shortcut (or locally if you left it blank).  In this case, it would be another instance of Typora of course. :)

I use this for instruction documents that include links to executables and scripts to follow certain documented procedures that are complicated enough to forget.  The especially great thing about this is of course that you can have parameters in the link files, and you can even write scripts to interact with the human reading the document.

The world becomes your oyster. :)