# How can I put a link that execute bash script from an asciidoc document?

Tags: asciidoc

I am trying to manage programs at my computer using asciidoc.I know that asciidoc is markup language but sometimes I need this feature.

For example, open the specific project using IDE and go to the specific code block.

I have tried bash script file but it didn't work on AsciidocFX(asciidoc preview program).

```
   link:script.sh[Do the job]
```

In markdown, this feature can be achieved like this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/42911034/9134980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done.
AsciiDoc is a *markup* language; it does not try and execute programs.

The link you provide for Markdown *links* to a PDF: it does not execute the PDF.

Write a proper script and run that to do what you want.