# Change file paths to make links to local files work in VSCode Markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, hyperlink, markdown

When I copy a file path from the Windows file explorer and paste it into VSCode, it looks like that:

```
\\network_name\project\file 1.txt
```

For the link to be clickable and point to the right location, I figured that I needed to make 3 modifications: change the backslashes to forward ones, add "file:" at the beginning of the link, and replace spaces by "%20" (yes, my colleagues put spaces in file names everywhere, I can't do anything about that). The working link is the following:

```
file://network_name/project/file%201.txt
```

**I want to be able to change all file paths from the pasted version to the working version at once in the open Markdown document in VSCode. How can I achieve that?** It seems that this is the job for an extension, but I can't find one that does it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use relative links like explained in next solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59226851/1654688

Also, to use absolute path, this works for me:

```
[Folder](<file:///C:/Users/username/folder/filename.md>)
```

Note that including the path inside <> is intended to allow using spaces in the path or filename

Comment: The trick to allow spaces is helpful, thanks. I'm not sure the rest answers my question. I understand what links work and do not work in VS Code Markdown. What I would like to have is a way to automatically transform non-working links (as copied and pasted from the Windows File Explorer) to working ones.

Comment: I'm also finding a solution to this. Probably an available extension could do the job, but I don't like to install 3th party extensions from un-trusted sources yet...

Comment: I had some bother with this initially following the answer above.  The angle brackets `< >` works fine for allowing space, thanks for that.  These two examples link to a PDF file on Ubuntu: `[Linux logs](<//home/share/notes/linux/System Logs and the Syslog Standard.pdf>)` and `[Linux logs](//home/share/notes/linux/System%20Logs%20and%20the%20Syslog%20Standard.pdf)`.  Just one leading slash, not a [Uniform Naming Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) (UNC) path as I'd expected.